# Keyboard shortcut to take screenshots

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to take screenshots when I press Ctrl + Prtsc and have them saved as PNG images in C:\Users\Me\Pictures\Screenshots

Can I configure Windows 7 to do this? If not, what freeware applications would you recommend (preferably something that I never have to see again (i.e. it sits quietly in the system tray) once I install and configure it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gadwin](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) Print Screen is pretty quick to do this. After configuring, you can achieve what you need with a <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> and one (perhaps 2) <kbd>Return</kbd>s.

Comment: See my expanded answer for how to get proper one click printscreening.

Answer (score 3):

*Expanding on the answer given by outsideblasts:*

You can achieve exactly this using [Gadwin Printscreen](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/) ([Download](http://www.gadwin.com/download/index.htm#PrintScreen))

These are the settings you'll need to change:

[image]

With both of those off you wont be prompted at all and a simple <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> will save a screenshot in the set format to the set destination folder.

Comment: Nice. well done

Answer (score 1):

Jing by TechSmith is a great app and free for the basic version http://www.jingproject.com/ I use it myself. You can set up any key combo you like for it. A paid upgrade gives you a few more features and it integrates well with TechSmith's Snagit software which is also recommended (but not free).

Use Snipping Tool in Windows 7 if you don't want to install software. Here's how to get a key combo for the app http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/assign-a-shortcut-key-to-the-snipping-tool-in-windows-vista/ , but you will not be able to assign Prt Sc.

Answer (score 0):

'[picpick](http://picpick.wiziple.net/)' is able to achieve what you want, nice app.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the product here, and provide the link for reference.