# How can I automatically save screenshots to Dropbox?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, screenshot

I'm looking for an easy way to grab screenshots and put them in my public Dropbox folder. Preferably I could also easily grab the direct sharing url.

Bonus points for suggestions that let me select an area rather than the whole active screen.

It should at least work on Windows 7 and I'd prefer a free solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Faststone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) can do some of this (including capturing only part of the screen). It allows you to specify a location to put the file and will even autosave (assuming you have Dropbox setup as a folder).

[image: screenshot with highlights]

I love the program and use it daily to capture screenshots for training, documentation and for error codes.

Answer (score 6):

Not freeware, but you can accomplish the same thing with SnagIt.

[image]

Create an All-In-One profile (allows for regions or entire screen) and have an autosave to the Public folder in DropBox (gives you direct sharing URL)

Answer (score 3):

I find [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) one of the best. It's light, fast, and has many options quick to access with right mouse button on the notification area icon.

Also, it's free and open source software.

Comment: I'm actually using this right now, so a big +1 for you!

Comment: It's a great app with cool dropbox plugin

Comment: I prefer Lightscreen over this, as a general screenshot app, because Greenshot didn't allow me to edit the default hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

> [Dropbox Screen Grabber](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=13805&replies=23) is a simple
>   application which sits in the system
>   tray and allows you to capture the
>   screenshot of the whole desktop or the
>   currently active window and save it to
>   the Dropbox public folder.
>
> If you specify your Dropbox user ID in
>   the settings, application can also
>   automatically copy your public file
>   URL to the clipboard after taking the
>   screenshot.

Comment: Sorry I cheated :P

Comment: I installed that one too ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com) is a free, open-source tool that runs on Windows, can capture screen shots or partial screen shots, and drop them where you want - on a filesystem folder, on Imgur.com, on Amazon S3, and in other places.

There's [a set of plugins](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com), also open source, that extends the "output" options for Cropper. One of them allows you to immediately open the image in Paint.NET , for example.

Comment: Glad you like it.  I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox now has screenshot functionality built-in.](https://www.dropbox.com/help/photos-videos/screenshots)

> ### Windows Vista/7/8/10
>
> - Press **Print Screen** to save the screenshot to your Dropbox.
> - Press **Ctrl + Print Screen** to save the screenshot to your Dropbox and copy a link to the screenshot that you can immediately paste
>     anywhere, such as an email message or a Facebook post. Anyone who
>     clicks on the link will see your screenshot on a preview page on the
>     Dropbox website.
>
> ### Macintosh
>
> - To capture the entire screen, press **Command-Shift-3**.
> - To capture a part of the screen, press **Command-Shift-4**. Draw a rectangle over an area with your cursor, or press the spacebar and
>     click on a window.

You can enable or disable screenshot sharing in Dropbox's preferences menu.

[image: Screenshot settings]

Answer (score 0):

I consider freeware and simple is the best: "Gadwin Printscreen". It has many features, [give it a look](http://download.cnet.com/Gadwin-PrintScreen/3000-2094_4-10123018.html?tag=mncol;1)

Comment: This sounds like the winner - just set the captured folder to your dropbox and bingo
See this post on how to automate the process
http://superuser.com/questions/127197/keyboard-shortcut-to-take-screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Microsoft Snipping Tool found in accessories in the start menu.

[image: Microsoft Snipping Tool]